# building for android with expo

Tags: react-native, build, apk, expo

I'm trying to build my react-native app but I keep getting this error.

[image]

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "NuCamp",
    "slug": "nucampsite",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "co.nucamp.nucampsite.student"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "co.nucamp.nucampsite.student"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

this is my first time doing this and I'm completely lost. I tried searching for other people that had the same problems but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

you are using expo-cli@3.9.1, as the warning explains there is a much newer version and you should install it and use it instead :) that will resolve your issue